# RPi GPIO control with NodeRed under docker error?

Tags: docker, node-red, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to turn on and off an led in node red that runs under a docker container on the pi
I have to mention I don't understand docker that well and after I deploy the GPIO node and connect it it shows under the node "ECONNREFUSED localhost:8888"
I've tried enabling the GPIO control over web in raspi-config but with no luck...

any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem will be that `localhost` will point to inside the container, not the host OS.

Try editing the node to point to `172.17.0.1` (the default host IP address for Docker)

And make sure pigpiod is running in the host OS

Comment: Well So I've used 172.17.0.0:8888 and it does seem to behave differently and gives Green box instead of ECONNREFUSEF but changes to ETIMEOUT afterwards and it doesn't affect the GPIO PIN (tested the led with python)

Comment: You need to make sure the pigpiod daemon is running in the host OS (and probably make sure it's listening on more than just 127.0.0.1)

Comment: And you've not copied the IP address I listed

Comment: So I've tested with 172.17.0.0 because it gave me a different result last night and now after enabling that pigpiod daemon like you said and it works with 172.17.0.1:8888 I've followed this thread: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70568/how-to-run-pigpiod-on-boot  to do that. Thank you very much for the help!